# Quick question about conjuctions

Tags: english-to-german, conjunction

I'm learning German by myself and the conjunctions started to make me crazy, therefore I can't understand why the grammar of the sentence is totally different when we use conjunctions.

And, do these sentences mean exactly the same or not?

1. Wir mögen sie, weil sie magt uns.
2. Weil er uns mag, mögen wir ihn.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Did you mean your examples you wrote them? Because 1st example has some spelling errors which I don't want to correct if you know them by yourself. In case you don't see them, it is fine, correcting them then will become part of an answer.

Comment: Can you explain the errors on 1st one if possible, please?

Comment: As the errors have nothing to do with your question, this is my assumption of what you intended to write: `Wir mögen sie, weil sie uns mag.` I'm not fully sure about the necessity of the comma, so I leave it untouched. While correcting: "conjunction" also in title, please. And avoid "quick question". And no "drives me craze" - more a neutral description of your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm The word order is acceptable, as nowadays the verb no longer needs to be at the end in a subordinate clause; though it is more colloquial.

Comment: @Oliver Mason: I don't know who told you that, but it's plain out wrong. Many people mix up *weil* and *denn*, though. *Denn* means the same as *weil* but its dependent clause has main clause order.

Comment: @Janka Nobody told me that. It's based on my own experience of speaking German for about 50 years.

Comment: Apart from the theoretical discussion, I am wondering what the sense of this sentence should be. "We like her because she likes us" is hard to motivate from a logical perspective.

Answer (score 6):

The sentences would mean the same, if you used the same pronoun in both sentences, like:

1) Wir mögen sie, weil sie uns mag.

2) Weil sie uns mag, mögen wir sie.

German word order rules require (with some conjunctions as exception) that in sub-clauses (e.g. one starting with "weil") the conjugated verb goes to the end, while in main clauses it goes to the second position.

In sentence 1) the positions of the words are easy to count: the main clause has "mögen" at position two: Wir mögen sie, while the sub-clause starting with "weil" has "mag" at the end: weil sie uns mag.

In sentence 2) you count the same as in 1) in the sub-clause, just that the sub-clause is at the beginning. But the main clause: mögen wir sie, seemingly contradicts the rule, as it starts with "mögen". Here you have to known, that the preceding sub-clause as a whole counts as position one, which make "mögen" in accordance with the rule for main clauses be at second position.

Answer (score 2):

*Why the grammar of the sentence is totally different when we use conjunctions?*

The main clause is the exception. You just happen to learn it first, and those German examples you were taught resemble English word order. But that is because the examples are deliberately chosen that way. German does not follow English word order at all.

The default German word order puts all predicate verbs to the end of the clause, in reverse order of importance. The finite verb ends up as the last word in the clause.

Deviating from that general rule, in declarative main clauses **the stem of the finite verb** (and only that stem!) is moved to second position instead. All in front of it is one huge item, the topic of the main clause. That stem is used as a kind of marker that splits the topic from the rest of the main clause.

Only in the narrow corner case of a main clause with the subject being the topic, and the tense not using an auxiliary, German sentences roughly resemble English sentences.

Comment: "The default German word order puts all predicate verbs to the end of the clause, in reverse order of importance. The finite verb ends up as the last word in the clause". This does not hold at all. " Ich esse jeden Tag mit Freunden". You are probably referring to subordinated clauses.

Comment: I seriously doubt you've read my answer thoroughly. Otherwise you would have understood what it means and that it is in fact correct. (Yes, it challenges your prior knowlegde. That doesn't make it wrong.)

Comment: Yes, I have and a statement like "The default German word order puts all predicate verbs to the end of the clause, in reverse order of importance. The finite verb ends up as the last word in the clause" is simply not correct unless you distinguish between main and subordinated clauses. By the way, what do you mean by "reverse order of importance"? What do you mean by "stem of the finite verb"? It would be nice if you could illustrate your whole assertion through a short example.

Comment: My answer distinguishes main and dependent clauses from the first few words on. If you can't see that there's nothing I could do.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You don't write "The default German word order puts all predicate verbs to the end of the SUBORDINATE clause". Moreover, I kindly asked you to provide an example for different points of your assertion. That could be easily done and would help people other than me understand what you mean.

Comment: *The main clause is the exception.* What do you don't understand about this sentence? It's simple.

Comment: Exception to what? Main clauses behave very regularly. They are not exceptions.

Comment: No. They don't. Main clauses are the huge exception. They split up the finite verb into stem and prefix. They put the stem into V2 position. All other verbs stick to the end. Prefixes stick to the end. *Nicht* sticks to the end.

Comment: I'll just leave it. You do not seem to be able to demonstrate your assertions through examples, which is what it is required here.

Comment: @Nico - no need for an example. He could just show the usual sentences. But it's another way (I would even say equivalent way) of thinking about the same thing, an explanation that some people find simpler and some just weird, as they never heard it explained that way before. So you either accept the prerequisite or not. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's not about accepting, but about making one's points clear by illustrating them. I doubt the asker would understand a theoretical explanation such as the one above (let us leave its correctness aside for the time being).